# Why the database is empty?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have this in MainActivity:

```
    db = new Database(this);
```

And the Database.java:

```
public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "days.db";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "days";
    public static final String COLUMN_1 = "date";
    public static final String COLUMN_2 = "blob";
    private Context context;


    public Database(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("create table IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME + " (" + COLUMN_1 + " TEXT, " + COLUMN_2 + " BLOB)");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        onCreate(db);
    }

}
```

But if I open the database in SQLite DB Browser it is empty. No table created. Can anyone copy-paste my code and fix it?

Comment: this code never create sqlite db brower also table

Comment: You created the database helper but you haven't created the database. You need to call `getWritableDatabase`

Comment: On what? And where?

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
SQLiteDatabase db = new Database(this).getWritableDatabase();

getWritableDatabase ()
```

When this method is called, the required methods like onCreate(SQLiteDatabase), onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase, int, int) and onOpen(SQLiteDatabase) are called and the tables created.

Comment: Where should I try this line?

Comment: where u r calling  new Database(this); there replace "SQLiteDatabase db = new Database(this).getWritableDatabase();"

Comment: @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_diary);

        SQLiteDatabase db = new Database(this).getWritableDatabase();

    }

Comment: where u r writing ur db in internal storage

Comment: http://techin-android.blogspot.com/2011/08/how-to-create-sqlite-databse-in-sdcard.html  for creating ur db in internal memory

Comment: public Database(final Context context) {
    super(context, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + File.separator + FILE_DIR
            + File.separator + DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}       try this on ur database class constructor

Answer (score 0):

try it : i put here simple db for u its worked for me

```
 public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private Context context1;

public Database(Context context) {

    super(context, "CREATECONTACT", null, 1);
    this.context1 = context;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String query = "CREATE TABLE createContact ( \n" +
            "    ID          INTEGER        PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT\n" +
            "                               NOT NULL\n" +
            "                               UNIQUE,\n" +
            "    Name        VARCHAR( 50 )  NOT NULL,\n" +
            "    Phone       VARCHAR        NOT NULL,\n" +
            "    typeofPhone VARCHAR        NOT NULL,\n" +
            "    Email       VARCHAR        NOT NULL,\n" +
            "    typeofEmail VARCHAR        NOT NULL,\n" +
            "    FAVE        VARCHAR        NOT NULL,\n" +
            "    RED         INTEGER,\n" +
            "    GREEN       INTEGER,\n" +
            "    BLUE        INTEGER \n" +
            ");\n";
    db.execSQL(query);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS createContact");
    onCreate(db);
}
```

Comment: But if I open the database in SQLite DB Browser it is empty. 
man dont show visiual u dont must think if u run this code it will be create a table when u open sql db

Comment: What kind of language is that?